# php return two value array object

Tags: php, arrays

what i am trying to do is to set two attribute via the object in the the class then get this attribute but i need to echo or to print the value to make sure , more explanation in the fowling code :

```
class product 
{
  var $title=" ";
  var $price=" "; 
  function __construct($title1,$price1)
  {
    $this->title=$title1;
    $this->price=$price1;
  }
  function set_title($newtitle){
    $this->title=$newtitle;
  }
  function get_title() {
    return $this->title;
  }
  function set_price($newprice)
  {
    $this->price=$newprice;

  }
  function getProductAtrribute ()
  {

     $x1=$this->title;
     $x2=$this->price; 

     return   $allattribute= array("$x1","$x2");


  }
}

$chair = new product(" small","chair");
$chair->getProductAtrribute();
```

after i get the attribute i am struggling for echo the attribute or print they value of the array $allattribute=arra("$x1,"$x2");
please help how i can print those value .

Comment: `$allattribute = $chair->getProductAtrribute();  echo $allattribute[0] . " ' . $allattribute[1];`

Comment: `var_dump($chair->getProductAtrribute());`

Comment: i did not understand i !

Comment: @saiedtrifess, `var_dump` above. Is it work?

Comment: @saiedtrifess, both suggestion does what you need above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
print_r($chair->getProductAtrribute());
```

Or

```
var_dump($chair->getProductAtrribute());
```

Comment: should add this in the function or outside ?

Comment: Outside, where you want to print.

Answer (score 0):

Nor sure what you are asking but this looks like it:

```
$prod = $chair->getProductAtrribute();
echo $prod[0].'<br>';
echo $prod[1];
```

Comment: i set the value ("small ","chair"), one for the title and one for attribue and i put then in the array as you can see in the function , getallattribute , just need to print those tow value

Comment: My reply and the one from splash58 will both do that for you.